# python syntax for param in params

Tags: python, syntax

Need some help with Python syntax

Pesudo code

> if param is not None in params, param replace('xx', 'x')

I get this far:

```
param.replace('|', '/') for param in ("bar|one","bar|two")
```

My question is how to add a None check in this line of code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
[ param.replace("|", "/") if param is not None else None for param in iterable ]
```

Or maybe a tiny bit more legible if we switch the logic around just a bit:

```
[ None if param is None else param.replace("|", "/") for param in iterable ]
```

I like the second version a little better because if breaks up the `None else None` nonsense that was present in the first one...

This differs slightly from the (initial) answer by @Tim Pietzcker.  His (initial) answer will filter `None` values out of the input iterable whereas this answer will pass them through.

---

Here we use the python [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (which is sometimes known as the "ternary operator" in other languages).  The syntax is:

```
value_if_true if conditional_expression else value_if_false
```

Comment: +1 for preserving the `None` entries, as opposed to removing them as in the other answer.

Comment: Ah, I was editing my answer to take that into account while you were writing yours :)

Answer (score 7):

```
[param.replace('|', '/') for param in params if param is not None]
```

This will silently remove all `None` params from your input list, so

```
("bar|one", None, "bar|two")
```

would become

```
["bar/one","bar/two"]
```

If you don't want that, use

```
[param.replace('|', '/') if param is not None else None for param in params]
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends...

Do you want to want to retain the None elements? If so:

```
[(each.replace('|', '/') if each is not None else None) for each in listOfWords]
```

If you want to filter the Nones out, then you can do:

```
[each.replace('|', '/') for each in listOfWords if each is not None]
```